# How to chose appropriate finite limits for NIntegrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to `NIntegrate` a function using finite limits so it gives a result as close as possible to a result which I would get making the limit `\[Infinity]`.

When I have a function that is easy to `NIntegrate` in the limit from `0` to `\[Infinity]` I can just try different finite limits until I get a result matching the `\[Infinity]` case. However, I want to find a method of determining that limit (small enough to be managable by Mathematica but giving a proper result) when the function cannot be integrated to `\[Infinity]` to check the answer.

Here's what I tried on a specific example:
I have a function

`fvackx[kx_] :=(0.0579484 Sin[3.2 kx])/kx`

First, I `NIntegrate` it from `0` to `\[Infinity]` so I'll have a point od reference. The result is

`NIntegrate[fvackx[kx], {kx, 0, \[Infinity]}]`

> 0.0910251

I want to find a limit, smaller than `\[Infinity]` so I get the result matching the `0.0910251`.

I checked how the `NIntegrate` result changes with different integration limits:

1. Create a `NIntegrate` function that allows putting different limits `a`

`NIkx[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[fvackx[kx], {kx, 0, a}]`

2. Create a list of results for limits ranging from `100` to `100000`

`list = Table[{a, NIkx[a]}, {a, 100, 100000, 100}];`

3. Plot the results

[image]

What I understand from it is that the in order for the limit to be realistic and reliable it shouldn't be bigger than `6000` - higher than that and the result is all over the place. But how to determine what specifically it should be? I see that the result is very consistent in a range up to `1500` so I tried fitting a line to see what's the mean resulting number

`listkx1 = Table[{a, NIkx[a]}, {a, 100, 1500, 100}];`

`fitkx1 = Fit[listkx1, {1, l}, l]`

> 0.0909817 + 4.08923*10^-8 l

My idea was that knowing this line function will give me an idea of what the result of `NIntegrate` should be and I could check different limits to try to match the `Fit` result. But I still need to know what limit `l` should I put to be precise. When I use only the constant part `0.0909817` it's somewhat close to my (known in this example) base but I want to be able to find a better number that matches more. In my example I know that `1100` will give me a nice result close to the real one

`NIntegrate[fvackx[kx], {kx, 0, 1100}]`

> 0.0910226

By using the `Fit` method and putting the `l=1100` I also get a close number

> 0.0910267

That method isn't a solution though, because what I want to do is to determine the limit without having a point of reference in a function where integrating to `\[Infinity]` isn't possible. I have no other ideas

Comment: Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: No, that's just a function example that's simple and easily gives results. When I have a complicated function that needs to be integrated numerically I need to know what limit to set. It's not a case of "the bigger the limit the more precise the result". A realistic result in some cases will be in a finite limit that isn't a maximum one that Mathematica can handle (I talk about a case where integrating to infinity is completely undoable)

Comment: This sounds like a numerical precision issue which you can control by rationalizing 0.0579484 and 3.2 (to 144871/2500000 and 32/10, respectively) and by using the  `WorkingPrecision` in `NIntegrate`.

Comment: There is a "compact" solution for your simpler example:  `a SinIntegral[kx b]` where `a = Rationalize[0.0579484, 0]` and `b = 32/10`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to use NMinimize, which searches for a global minimum of a function. In order to use this with NIntegrate, first define an auxiliary function to insure the symbolic argument being varied has a numerical value before evaluating the integral:

```
f[ulim_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[fvackx[kx], {kx, 0, ulim}];
```

Now minimize (f[upperlimit]-target)^2, where the target is the value you get from integrating out to infinity. The idea is to minimize the difference after squaring to handle positive/negative deviations on the same footing.

```
NMinimize[(f[ulim] - 0.0910251350487245`)^2, ulim]
 {3.08149*10^-33, {ulim -> 1.52932}}
```

This is much smaller than the values you're working with. These plots gives an indication of why:

```
Plot[(f[x] - 0.0910251350487245`)^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

[image]

Basically the your function is oscillatory with a small period, so you attain a value close to your desired result close to the origin. If you wish, you can restrict the domain NMinimize searches in, or apply further constraints - see the documentation for examples.